# How fast WP7 would close app on deactivation via Windows button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, tombstoning

Wondering, what i'd be able to do before app would be deactivated?

- If i'm sending a network request and user would press Windows before answer would come, request would be cancelled and a RequestCancelled exception would be thrown on app reactivation ( due to [this article](http://community.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2012/04/08/what-happens-to-network-calls-when-your-wp7-app-goes-dormant.aspx)).
- If i have to write something asyncly to the isostorage, would it be done?

So, how fast app would be disabled? How much would i be able to store before disabling? Would i be able to save 1000 files asyncly?

Comment: If you have so many files to save, you should do it more regularly rather than doing it on the deactivating event.

Comment: @AD.Net Yep, i found a nice article about ConcurrentQueue: http://sharpsnippets.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/generic-concurrent-queue-1n/ And was considering, how useful it can be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Applications are given 10 seconds to complete the Deactivated handler.
>   If the event handler has not been completed before this time span has
>   elapsed, the application is terminated. It is recommended that
>   applications aim for 2 seconds for completing the handler to provide a
>   large buffer for unexpected delays. Applications should incrementally
>   save data to isolated storage and to the State property while the
>   application is running to reduce the amount of data storage that needs
>   to be performed in the Deactivated handler.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)